# Share an instance of a object between windows technique

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application with a MainWindow and the user click a login button that open a new window i created. in that new window.cs file i have the user type in username which is stored in a new instance of the user class. I want to have that username (stored in the new instance of the class) accessible in the MainWindow.cs

whats the best practice for this?

Comment: Make it a public property of the new window. But since it's a login window it should be modal, so you could return it from a ShowDialog() overload that calls base.ShowDialog().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always expose that through a `public` property on the login form, much like with `OpenFileDialog` :

```
void Login()
{
    var login = new LoginForm();
    if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var userName = login.UserName;
    }
}

public class LoginForm : Form
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }

    public void OnOKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // validation...

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.UserName = UserNameTextBox.Text;

        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```